# Leviticus 13:4 Quarantined where?

Tags: halacha, tzaraas-negaim

According to [Leviticus 13:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0313.htm#4), those suspected to have leprosy were to be quarantined.

Where were they quarantined?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/tzaraas-negaim/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shadal states that he is quarantined in his own house.

More interestingly, however, he quotes the Rash as saying that the translation of that verse is not "the kohen quarantines the one with the blemish" but rather "the kohen closes the blemish" with a line drawn around it, in order to determine if it is growing.

Comment: How would he explain verses 21 and 26 which say והסגירו in masculine about a feminine Baheret?

Comment: This is the opinion of the Meiri as well, IIRC.